# Why must the independent variable of a function to be plotted be a macro in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, pgfmath

Consider the following code (taken from Jake's answer) and focus on the variable of the function to be plotted.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [domain=0:50,variable=\t,smooth,samples=500]
        plot ({\t r}: {1+2*exp(-\t/10)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My question is quite simple, why must the variable be a macro (`\t` in this case) rather than just a letter (for example `t`) or a word (for example `theta`) as I think we usually use a letter  when using a graphics calculator or Computer Algebra Systems? PSTricks, for example, also does not need a macro when plotting. In PSTricks, `\psplot[algebraic]{-4}{4}{x^2-5*x+6}` where `x` is the independent variable and it does not need to be a macro `\x`.

The relevant case of using a macro is when we use a loop such as `\foreach \t in {1,...,2}{<do with \t>}`. But I don't think plotting needs such an iterating variable `\t` exposed to the users. Hopefully you understand what I don't understand.

You might think of why I made a fuss about it. Because the macro makes the function expression no longer natural, elegant, beautiful, simple, etc. For example, `t^2-5*t+6` becomes `\t*\t-5*\t+6` which is not natural and of course the existence of `\` consumes more keystrokes.

Do you think there is a benefit of the current syntax where the independent variable must be a macro?

Comment: Because `t` can be function name (as `sin`, `exp`...).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, but so can any name you could use as a PGFmath function. The `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` macro checks whether another PGFmath function with the same name already exists and throws an error in that case. Even worse, the macro you use could be an already used macro and would get overwritten (locally but still).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel In the function expression, all  PGFmath functions are potentially useful while any already used macro is rarely used.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: It will be a good idea too to let `t` be any numbers as variables. :-)

Comment: It depends on the tikz/pgf parser of course but your pstricks example of `x sin` not needing `\x` is misleading (or not relevant, or something). That is _PostScript_ syntax and to refer to the value stored in `x` in PostScript the syntax is `x` not `\x`.

Comment: Also if the pstricks example _is_ relevant then where does `t t mul 5 t mul sub 6 add` rate on the naturalness/keystroke scale when compared to `t^2-5*t+6`?

Comment: @MarkWibrow: But PSTricks has `algebraic` option for ones who strongly consider the number of keystrokes or naturalness.

Comment: @Marienplatz indeed, although the conversion is carried out at the postscript level. If you are interested in seeing this feature in PGF (rather than just trying to highlight a perceived failing in the package) you are welcome to file a feature request [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `pgfmath` parser was written, the main aim was to provide *consistent* and slightly more versatile mathematical operations than the `calc` package (which used to do all the calculations) without the overhead of the `fp` package. Also the integration with `\foreach` variables was important as well (as been suggested above).

So, every expression given to the `pgfmath` parser is `\edef`'ed immediately prior to parsing. This means that in most cases (unless you do something clever with `\noexpand` inside double quotes) that

- any unexpanded tokens are `TeX` registers
- the parser does not have to worry about checking whether tokens are expandable

As things stand it is possible to define a function which can stand for a plotting variable (as has been shown above). This is, to my knowledge, the only way of achieving the OPs requirements. But (as has also already been pointed out) parsing a number is quicker than parsing/evaluating a function.

As a "side note", I genuinely intended `pgfmath` to be a temporary fix for mathematical operations in`PGF` and thought that when `luatex` came along "proper" programmers would jump in and sort things out. Sadly that hasn't happened.

Comment: How many times is the parsing performed? Once before start plotting or `N` times (one parsing per iteration) where `N` represents the plot points.

Comment: Since calculations cannot be left to the renderer and have to be performed by the package, parsing occurs _at least_ once, and most probably twice per point (quite often more) depending on calculations required by the plot handler.

Answer (score 4):

Why? I don’t know.

Though, TikZ doesn’t do anything else but to iterate over the domain. When TikZ plots a function it uses the PGF macro `\pgfplotfunction` for this. In our case it is called with something like (the third parameter is not correct but this is essentially how you would do this in PGF)

```
\pgfplotfunction{\t}{0, 0.10019, ..., 50}{\pgfpointpolar{\t r}{1+2*exp(-\t/10)}
```

In the definition of `\pgfplotfunction` we find something like

```
% Initialize plotting
\foreach #1 in {#2}{
   % parse #3, extract x and y and sent it to the plotter
}
% Do the actual plotting
```

---

Here’s a way around it by defining a PGFmath variable that simply expands to the variable used by the plotter. To not overwrite any already defined macros like `\t` or `\theta` (which could be used by a node on the path), I “hid” the actual variable name in a m@cro.

```
\tikzset{
  variable*/.style={
    declare function={#1=\tikz@plot@var;},
    variable=\tikz@plot@var}}
```

You can now say `variable*=theta` and then use `theta` instead of `\t` in the function.

I have added a “fast” version in the code below because our variable is already calculated by the `\foreach` loop and doesn’t need additional parsing or evaluating. Thus, I copy the value of the iterator directly to `\pgfmathresult`.

---

Note that if you plot with gnuplot (an external tool to TeX and TikZ) by using the `function` plot operator as in

```
\draw plot[parametric, domain=0:50, samples=500, smooth]
        function {cos(t)*(1+2*exp(-t/10)), sin(t)*(1+2*exp(-t/10))};
```

you need to use the variables `x` and, for parametric plots, `t`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{variable*/.code=\pgfmathdeclarefunction{#1}{0}{\let\pgfmathresult\tikz@plot@var}%
                         \def\tikz@plot@var{\tikz@plot@var}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [domain=0:50,variable*=theta,smooth,samples=500]
        plot (theta r: {1 + 2 * exp( -theta / 10)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, is there any advantage of the current mechanism where the variable must be a macro?

Comment: @Marienplatz It probably is faster (depending on how PGFmath parses things but I guess that parsing a number is faster than checking for a possible function name (and possible options)). Using `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` also adds a few other auxiliary macros and itself takes time. — Note that I just realized that there is no need for yet another macro, we can just use `\tikz@plot@var` itself. :)

Comment: @Marienplatz On that topic, it seems that you can get away with `\pgfmath@namedef{pgfmath@function@#1}{\let\pgfmathresult\tikz@plot@var}\pgfmath@namedef{pgfmath@operation@#1@arity}{0}` reducing the needed macros to two and also only needing two `\def`s instead of a lot of the parsing the `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` does. But this will probably break somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

*(edit) 2017: since `xint 1.1 (2014/10/28)`, `xinttools` is not loaded by `xintfrac`. Code updated.*

---

Not that I recommend it at all, as the nice key=value syntax is lost, but it is possible to do a bit of the job done by `TikZ` and avoid having a macro for the variable in plots. But one still needs a macro, now for the expression giving the plotted points. I tried without but it appears that after `coordinates` one needs something completely expandable, so I could not use `\xintFor` there.

The macros `\Sample`,  `\SamplE` and `\SampleFit` are a bit undecipherable, what they do is to compute the `#1` which will be used by the macro `\PointMacro` (name arbitrary) corresponding to the actual plot. The `#1` will be a fixed point number with 4 digits after decimal mark.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xintfrac, xinttools}

% \Sample {N}\pointmacro {start:end}
% it returns expandably the N points from  N equispaced samples starting with
% start and ending with end.
% \pointmacro (name arbitrary) 
% should be a one-parameter macro which returns a point
% as recognized by tikz (such as (x,y), or (angle:radius))
% example \def\macro #1 {(#1, {(#1)^2})}
% see examples below

\def\Sample #1#2#3{\SamplE {#1}#2#3;}

\def\SamplE #1#2#3:#4;{\expandafter\xintApplyUnbraced\expandafter
     {\expandafter\SampleFit\expandafter #2\expandafter
       {\romannumeral0\xintdiv{\xintSub{#4}{#3}}{\xintDec{#1}}}{#3}}
     {\xintSeq{0}{#1-1}}}

\def\SampleFit #1#2#3#4{\expandafter #1\expandafter{\romannumeral0%
                       \xinttrunc {4}{\xintAdd{#3}{\xintMul{#2}{#4}}}}}

\begin{document}    
\tikzset {x=.5cm, y=.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\ParabolaPoint #1{(#1, {(#1)^2})}% negative #1 within parentheses!
    \draw [smooth] plot coordinates {\Sample {25}\ParabolaPoint {-2:2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\CubicPoint #1{(#1, {(#1)^3})}
    \draw [smooth] plot coordinates {\Sample {25}\CubicPoint {-1.25:1.25}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\SpiralPoint #1{({#1 r}: {1+2*exp(-#1/10)})}
    \draw [smooth] plot coordinates {\Sample {200}\SpiralPoint {0:50}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: parabola][image: cubic][image: spiral]

Comment: `\xintSeq {0}{#1-1}` in the `\SamplE` code generates `{0}{1}{2}..{N}` with `N=#1-1`. If `N` is too large (around `5000` on my installation) there is a problem with the input stack. This is explained in the `xint` documentation, and the fix is to use `\xintSeq [1]{0}{#1-1}` which does the same in an input stack compatible way. So if one wants `5000` sample points one should use a variant of `\SampleE` where a `[1]` has been inserted after `\xintSeq`.